# Angular material button not clickable when iterating over new objects when an input array is initialized from a Typescript getter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following bewildering Angular problem.

**Edit: I managed to reproduce this in the Stackblitz example, and updated the text here.**

Stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyup5j).

This shows four sets of three list entries with a delete icon, with the following pairings:

```
string input/passed from a getter
string input/passed from a field
array input/passed from a getter
array input/passed from a field
```

**In the array/getter case**, when I click the first (from `items1`), nothing is logged to the console; but clicking the second (from `items2`) or the third (from `items3`), it logs `'delete'`. In the other cases, it *always* logs delete, as expected.

**What might be going on here?**

Code follows, although the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyup5j) is easy to play with.

First, the parent HTML, which sets up the four cases:

```html
String with getter
<hello [name]="name1">
</hello>
<hr/>
String without getter
<hello [name]="name2">
</hello>
<hr/>
Array with getter
<hello [names]="names1">
</hello>
<hr/>
Array without getter
<hello [names]="names2">
</hello>
```

and Typescript:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  get name1(): string {
    return 'Angular';
  }
  name2 = 'Angular';
  get names1(): string[] {
    return ['Angular'];
  }
  names2 = ['Angular'];
}
```

And then the component HTML:

```html
<mat-list>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items1">
    <mat-list-item>
      <h2 mat-line>Some Text</h2>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="delete()"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-list-item>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items2">
    <mat-list-item>
      <h2 mat-line>Some Text</h2>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="delete()"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-list-item>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items3">
    <mat-list-item>
      <h2 mat-line>Some Text</h2>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="delete()"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-list-item>
  </ng-container>
</mat-list>
```

and Typescript:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() names: string[];

  items1: Number[] = [];
  items2: Number[] = [];
  items3 = [new Number(42)];

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.items1 = [new Number(42)];
    this.items2 = [42];
  }

  delete() {
    console.log('delete');
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried your code in a local project and it worked ok for me.

Comment: Just a random guess: Maybe your CSS is responsible for the behaviour. Is some invisible `div` maybe placed only above the first button and prevents the click event from getting triggered? You can check that by having a look at the layout within the devtools.

Comment: @pschild Good thought, but alas no dice; the rendered layout looks right to me (no strange divs or anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem here (although not the root cause) is that when using an `ngFor` loop, Angular uses object identity to track whether it needs to re-render. See the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation) for discussion. And so (see below) adding a `trackBy` function fixes the problem.

In the bad case here:

- Using a getter for input with a list causes `ngOnChanges` to be called twice, with the same value. Presumably Angular accesses the input twice (I don't know why), but when it does, the getter returns a new list each time, which has a different identity, so `ngOnChanges` gets called twice.
- It *doesn't* get called twice with the `string` getter; the `string` objects are identical.
- When `ngOnChanges` is called, it resets the bad list (`items1`) to contain new objects.

The upshot is that in this case, Angular renders the list twice, because it thought all elements changed from one pass to the next.

Now: I **don't know** why this causes the buttons to not be clickable. But Angular lets you override the `trackBy` function, which it uses to figure out if an element of a list has changed. And changing that to track by the index (which doesn't change here) fixes the problem.

Forked Stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eueiya) solving the problem, which adds:

To the component's Typescript:

```js
trackByIndex(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

and in the HTML loop:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items1; trackBy: trackByIndex">
  <mat-list-item>
    <h2 mat-line>Some Text</h2>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="delete()"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-list-item>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `hello.component.ts`, if you change
`this.items1 = [new Number(42)];` to `this.items1 = [42];`
it is working.

To be honest, I'm not able to tell you exactly why, but it works :-) Seems to have something to do with using the General Type `Number`, maybe in combinaton with Angular's ChangeDetection in `ngOnChanges()`. I personally know that those types exist, but never saw somebody using them.
Regarding that, I read something on the [TypeScript Do's and Dont's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html):

> Don’t ever use the types Number, String, Boolean, or Object. These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code.

That would mean you better should use the lower case ones, like `number` for specifying your types and not use the constructor to create new `Number`s.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I think the Number is a red herring. In my real code, I'm using a user-defined type; I just put Number in the example to avoid defining a new type, but nothing changes if you change it to, say, new Foo().

Comment: Although, of course, it adds to the mystery that a numeric literal works in `ngOnChanges` but creating a new object doesn't.

Comment: Also, note that your suggestion is the difference between `items1` and `items2`, and why I put both of them in the example :)

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially... sort of... creating recursion.

1. By passing an input to trigger `ngOnChanges` which intializes a value for `*ngFor`...
2. which then updates the view as the initial value was empty...
3. which then in turn triggers another `ngOnChanges` event when the view is "changed" and changes the underlying identity...
4. and so on... and so on...

As you pointed out with every iteration the "identity" changes..

> The identities of elements in the iterator can change while the
>   data does not.  * This can happen, for example, if the iterator is
>   produced from an RPC to the server, and that  * RPC is re-run. Even if
>   the data hasn't changed, the second response produces objects with  *
>   different identities, and Angular must tear down the entire DOM and
>   rebuild it (as if all old  * elements were deleted and all new
>   elements inserted).

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1c3ee41902ee742f6c62e053ddf3ee53ac78c7b5/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L110

wrapping the block inside of the `ngOnChanges` with a `setTimeout` and placing a `console.log` in there before it, will expose the underlying issue I am trying to illustrate and blow the stack...

- I know this is a very drastic example to illustrate what is going on here, but I think its important to take it to the extreme to understand what is happening with the approach you are attempting.

  ```
  ngOnChanges() {
          console.log('test')
          //setTimeout(()=>{
          // this.items1 = [new Number(42)];
          // this.items2 = [42];
          // })

        }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
        //passing the input to the *ngFor or figuring out some other way to update the 
        `hello.component` array would be a more stable solution. Leveraging `ngOnChanges` 
        to modify the view via component variable will not be a stable approach.

         for (const name in this.names) {
            this.items1 = [new Number(42)];
            this.items2 = [42];
          }
      }
  ```